# Changing font of a beamer presentation (Szeged-dove)

Tags: beamer, fonts, fontspec

I'd like to change the font of everything (but really everything) that appears in my beamer Szeged-dove presentation from *default* to some font I have the .ttf of (if that's relevant, I'm working on Overleaf).

Thanks very much in advance for any help!

Comment: If the answer below does not help, please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Disclaimer: I'm no font expert

If your font has sans serif letters, then it should be enough to use `\setsansfont` to change most (all) of the text in beamer

(replace the handwriting of Tycho Brahe with whatever font you want to use)

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{TychoElU.ttf}

\usetheme{Szeged}

\title{text}
\author{names}
\institute{institute}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{title}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{title}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]